# Sencha Touch- Retrieving XML data from server and store it in object

Tags: xml-parsing, sencha-touch

I was looking a way to get a xml data from the server and parse it in a object so i can access that data anywhere in my app. I found many code doing this by creating a model, Store and setting a proxy with XMLReader. Yeah this is good but there is a compulsion of creating store and proxies. Is there any way i can say this is my URL of xml data, get me the parsed xml in an object. I think for getting JSON we have a way like below.

```
Ext.util.JSONP.request({
    url: '<XYZ_URL>',        
    callbackKey: 'Successcallback',
    Successcallback: function(result) {
           console.log(result.data);   
           // Do your thing here
```

}});

Here we get a JSON data from the server and in the Successcallback function we get the JSON data as an Object in result. I can then save this result object globally and use it or travers through anywhere.

Can i do same thing with the XML data or i will get the XML data as string and then i need to parse it manually?

Comment: What is the problem with using a store? I mean they are there for a reason

Comment: Lets say I am not using lists or component with template defined. I have a tab bar and tab's title is coming from server in xml form. How do I tell tabPanel to use the data received from server as xml? it may a toolbar with n number of buttons with dynamic text.

Answer (score 0):

you can send Ajax request to the given Url and in success report method you can get your Desired data

```
     e.g.
          Ext.Ajax.request({
               url: 'some_url',
               success: function(response, opts) {                                                                                        
                           // parse the responseText
                           var data = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                           // save the username
                           localStorage.setItem("name", data.name);
                           localStorage.setItem("id", data.id);
                }
           });
```